# Unable to print values: print mmol/L instead of mg/dL. use:mmol/L = (mg/dL) / 18. Python code that prompts user for conversion

Tags: python

Unable to print values in range of 500. Any solution?

Here is my code:

```
import random

unit = input("Specify the units entered: , mmol/L or mg/dL")

while unit != 'mg/dL' or unit != 'mmol/L':
    if unit =='mg/dL':
        for i in range(0,500):
            print("blood glucose level" , i+1, '=', lst[i],'mg/dL')
        break

    elif unit == 'mmol/L':
        for i in range(0,500):
            print("blood glucose level ", i+1, "=" ,round(lst[i]/18,2),"mmol/L")
        break
    else :
        unit = input("wrong input entered . Renter the unit mmol/L or mg/dL")
```

Comment: Pls help need immediate help from someone

Comment: what is `lst`? in `lst[i]` for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from your code, what is `lst`, but if I print without it, things work:

```
print("blood glucose level" , i+1, '=', i,'mg/dL')
print("blood glucose level ", i+1, "=", round(i/18,2),"mmol/L")
```